# Passing data to Windows Service

Tags: c#, service, console-application

I have two application modes one is Console application and Windows Service both suppose to do the same job console will take user inputs and base on user inputs it will proceed with intended task and user inputs will be saved as user settings.

I need Windows service to use the same settings and do the same task in background with scheduling. Currently I'm facing the problem where user settings are not available when reading from Windows Service.

Comment: "where user settings are not available when reading from Windows Service" ... ??

Comment: I understand the problem, but I don't really understand the question. Apparently there is no canonical way to provide input to a Windows Service. Would it be an option to have the console application read its input from a file instead of from the console and use the same mechanism for the Windows Service?

Comment: first user need to run console app and from console app he needs to start windows service idea is job get scheduled and without running console app task executes through a service.

Comment: Andreas ,same code that works with Console app is not working for Windows Service null pointer exception is throwing.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the user settings (at time of running console app) in an `XML` file and read that file in your windows service and work accordingly

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible routes that I can think of to deal with this issue (I will update this later today with more detail when I have more time).

First, combine the applications into a single Program. Modify Program.cs so that you can pass in an argument telling it to run as a Console application or Service. This method helps you to make sure that you are doing the same thing in both uses, without repeating a lot of code.

Second, share the settings file between both projects. This seems to be the basic question you are asking. I'll elaborate on this when I have more time this evening.

Third, ask if you really need the service for what you are trying to do. If the service is only being run at certain times of the day, it might be better to instead focus on allowing the Console application to also run without input, as a Scheduled task.